# 'Refresh' or 'Back' in new tab

Tags: windows, browser, browser-tabs, microsoft-edge

In all desktop browsers, middle-clicking or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-clicking on a link opens it in a new tab. In at least Google Chrome (and perhaps other browsers), this also works with the *Refresh* and *Back* buttons; middle-clicking *Refresh* will open another copy of the page you are currently on in a new tab, while middle-clicking *Back* will open the last page you were on in a new tab.

In Microsoft Edge, these controls don't work, at least by default. Is there another shortcut I can use to get this functionality, or a way to enable these Chrome-style controls?

Comment: It seems to work for me...

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not implemented. You can submit your idea to Microsoft via the Windows Feedback Hub

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/06/12/how-windows-insider-feedback-influences-windows-10-development